# ls: show date of last updated file in directory tree, for each directory/file in list

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ls

I am looking for parameters to `ls`, or something equivalent, that do the following for a specified directory:

For each subdirectory:

- Look at each file and directory it contains, recursively.
- Find the file or directory with the most recent updated/modified date.
- Show this recursive updated date.
- Optionally, sort by this recursive updated date.

Afaik, the regular `ls -lArt` command only looks at the updated date of the folder itself, and not at the folder contents.

So, I am looking for an equivalent to what `du -hs * | sort -h` does for file size.

---

### Example

Consider the following directory structure.

```
- dir
  - subdir1:        last udpated 2013-07-07
    - subdir1a:     last updated 2012-01-01
      * file1a1.txt last updated 2016-02-22
    * file1b.txt:   last updated 2016-01-06
    * file1c.txt:   last updated 2015-12-30

  - subdir2:        last updated 2016-03-10
    * file2a.txt:   last updated 2016-02-04

  * file3.txt:      last updated 2014-02-13
```

The output for `ls-special dir` (sorted) would be like this:

```
file3.txt: last updated 2014-02-13
subdir1:   last updated 2016-02-22
subdir2:   last updated 2016-03-10
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't seem to understand what du -hs * does. It bears no resemblance to what you describe. Secondly, ls has no option to do what you ask. Use find, sort and tail instead.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: "it has no option to do what you ask. Use find, sort and tail instead." Ok fine, so the "or something equivalent" from my question applies. An answer that explains how to use find + sort + tail to achieve the above could be totally fine and in scope.

Comment: "Firstly, you don't seem to understand what du -hs * does." How so? I used it a dozen times today. It recursively aggregates the file size for each directory. Likewise, the command (combo) I am looking for recursively finds the most recent file update date for each directory. The intent is very similar. Technically it may be different, but so what.

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: I get more search results by using "modified" instead of "updated" :) https://startpage.com/do/search?q=linux+sort+directories+by+last+modified+file+recursively though not really happy with any of the results yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo -n {}; cd "{}"; ls -ltd * | grep -v ^d | head -n 1 | awk "{\$1=\$2=\$3=\$4=\$5=\$6=\$7=\$8=\"\"; print \$0}"; echo"" ' \;
```

What this does: first locate all sub-directories of the starting directory, then execute the `-exec` part:

```
echo -n {}; cd "{}"; ls -ltd * | grep -v ^d | head -n 1 | awk "{\$1=\$2=\$3=\$4=\$5=\$6=\$7=\$8=\"\"; print \$0}"; echo""
```

This spawns a new shell (one per sub-directory), prints the sub-directory's name, moves into it, ranks by access time (`-t`) everything (*i.e.*, files and directories) in long format (`-l`) without expanding the directories' content (`-d`). The long format is needed so that we can weed out directories (`grep -v ^d`), taking only the first line of output (`head -n 1`) which is the most recently accessed **file**, then (`awk`) we print only its name (not all other arguments), keeping in mind that its name might contain spaces: lastly, it prints a newline, so that directories with **no** content do not get mixed with the next one.

Keep in mind there is no way to distinguish *ex aequo*s in modification time.

Comment: This does not provide a listing as in the example in the question. Instead of listing only the toplevel directories, it lists all subdirectories, recursively. And instead of showing the updated date/time for each list item, it just shows a file name per entry.

Comment: But chapeau for the effort. It looks complex :)

Comment: I think it would be easier and more transparent with "real" programming. That is, a script with loops and variables. Unfortunately I am really bad at shell script. I should familiarize myself with another language besides php, for this kind of stuff. (probably would be possible with php, but it just feels wrong)

Comment: @donquixote You know, the modifications needed to achieve what you wish are truly simple. Will you take care of them or do you want me to include them in my answer?

Comment: If you don't mind including it, go ahead! I am currently still overwhelmed by too many levels of piping. It definitely should be part of the answer, so it matches the question (which I hope is more clear with the added example). If not for me, then for others who might find this.

Comment: "keeping in mind that its name might contain spaces" – and newlines, backslashes, unprintable characters… `ls` doesn't handle them well in the first place ([*Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). The reliable way is to use null-terminated strings (compare my solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1224295/432690)) but it's often a pain.

Answer (score 1):

The following command lists all files of the current tree (.) with newest file shown last:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -lart
```