# Calling a bash function isn't working as it should to change to recent directory?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, .bash-profile

So I expect my function to change to a recently modified directory.

This is it:

```
function cdrc { echo 'cd "$(ls -t | HEAD -1)"'; }
```

When I want to change to a recent dir:

```
$~ cd Desktop/Folder
$~ cdrc
```

I get:

> -bash: Desktop: Command not found

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your function is not working

There are few reasons:

- I guess `echo` is an artifact used for testing the syntax or so. It makes no sense if you want the function to do what you described.
- Uppercase `HEAD`. In Linux it should be `head`. I'm not sure about other OS-es where you can run `bash` and `head`. `HEAD` may or may not work in some of them but `head` should work everywhere.
- Parsing `ls` is not recommended. There is [an article about it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The main point in your case would be that `ls` cannot reliably print names including special or unprintable characters.
- There's no logic to test directories only, you may end up trying to `cd` to a file when there's no directory.
- There's no logic to handle the situation when the current working directory is empty.

All these issues can be debugged except this parsing `ls` thing. It's a design flaw. If you think `ls` limitations won't bite you then you can go with a solution from [this another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1223963/432690).

To do some tests you may create a troublesome directory with `mkdir "$(echo -ne "foo\nbar")"`; `ls`-based solutions will probably fail if this is the directory `cdrc` should `cd` to. To remove the troublesome directory invoke `rmdir "$(echo -ne "foo\nbar")"`.

I managed to create a safer function.

---

### Solution

```
function cdrc { cd "$(find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec stat --printf "%Y %n\0" {} + | sort -znr | head -zn 1 | cut -f 2- -d " ")" ;}
```

---

#### Explanation

To explain my function I shall write it more clearly. Note a `\` at the very end of a line tells `bash` the command continues in the next line; so my code below is treated as a one-liner, it can be pasted as a whole to interactive `bash`.

```
function cdrc { \
  cd "$( \
    find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec \
      stat --printf "%Y %n\0" {} + |
    sort -znr |
    head -zn 1 |
    cut -f 2- -d " " \
  )" \
;}
```

The procedure is as follows:

- At first `find` is run. It doesn't descend to subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`), it doesn't find the current directory either (`-mindepth 1`). It finds directories only (`-type d`). Then the `stat` command is run (thanks to `-exec`):

  - `stat` prints time of last data modification (`%Y`, mtime, seconds since Epoch), single space and name (`%n`). Due to `--printf` option it doesn't add the newline character but interprets `\0` as a null character that should be added at the end of every line.
  - `{}` is a part of `find -exec` syntax. During `find` execution it is replaced by directory name so `stat` knows what its target is.
  - `+` is also a part of `find -exec` syntax. It causes `find` to pass *multiple* names to single `stat` (and `stat` can handle it). This way fewer `stat` processes are created, it's faster.

At this moment we have zero or more lines. They look similar to this:

```
1493488341 directory name
1497365306 troublesome?directory name
```

but they are null-terminated, so even if there are names with troublesome characters, they will be handled properly. In the first column there are mtimes without leading spaces (I checked `stat` behavior with numbers of various length to be sure), then the first space separates mtime from directory name.

- This output is processed furhter:

  - `sort` sorts lines according to numerical value (`-n`), uses reverse order (`-r`) and works with null-terminated strings (`-z`). This way the directory we need is now in the first line.
  - Then `head` leaves the first line only (`-n 1`); it's also told to work with null-terminated strings (`-z`).
  - `cut` cuts the line, treating space as delimiter (`-d " "`) and leaving the second field and everything that follows (`-f 2-`), i.e. everything after the first space. It works with null-terminated strings (`-z`). The final output is the desired directory name.

Note the output will be empty if there's no directory in the current working directory.

- `$(…)` is replaced by the output of everything that is inside. At this moment we have either `cd "some directory name"` or `cd ""`. The former command does what you want; the latter (when there's no directory) does nothing.

The function will fail if the directory it's supposed to `cd` to is (re)moved/renamed after `find` finds it. Also `stat` may throw error(s) if any directory is (re)moved/renamed when the function works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all directories, i.e. starting with a dot

```
function cdrc { cd "$(ls -1atp|grep -v '^\.\.\?/$'|grep '/$'|head -1)"; }
```

Otherwise much simplier

```
function cdrc { cd "$(ls -1tp|grep '/$'|head -1)"; }
```